# Как экранировать специальные символы?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, экранирование

Уже не первый сталкиваюсь с тем, что, когда в поле с типом **TEXT** вместе с текстом записывается символ плюс (**+**), получаю не корректное поведение. Либо текст не записывается, либо не выводится, либо частично выводится/записывается. Я понимаю, что символ плюса может быть частью SQL-инструкции, но как обойти этот момент не знаю. Может какая-то волшебная функция для PHP существует?

ps
 функция addslahes из php не помогает.

Comment: Начните наконец пользоваться PDO и подготовленными запросами: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Visman , я сейчас с помощью activerecord пишу там уже есть PDO

Comment: Значит вы неправильно пишите ;)

Comment: Пример своего кода покажите, в котором видно данные, запрос и как эти данные через этот запрос вы записываете в базу.

Comment: @Visman `$mdl = new Message; $mdl->content = "hello + world";` и в базу попадает "hello world"

Comment: Посмотрел https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord если о нем речь шла. Действительно через PDO работает и подготовленные выражения. Может у вас проблема с валидаторами? Еще логирование запросов включите (пример класса logger тут есть http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/1/topics/684-sql-injection )

Comment: @Visman , нет валидации, этот класс пустой (только родительские данные) , лог включен и чист . напрямую запись через консоль базы инсерт правильный делает. теперь в голову приходит только запись напрямую без activerecord ну или запись с помощью конвертирования в коды символов. засада в общем...

Comment: @Visman не знаю в чем причина но помогла функция pg_escape_string

Comment: @perfect если там PDO под капотом, в этом не должо быть необходимости. В теории. Наверное, это баг и его стоит зарепортить.

Comment: @D-side видимо PG особенная вот тут про это написано http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-escape-string.php

Comment: @perfect не вижу, где. Зато вижу это: "You should prefer to use pg_query_params, i.e. use parameterized queries, rather than using pg_escape_string. Or use the newer PDO interface with its parameterized query support."

Comment: @D-side вот: Функция pg_escape_string() является наиболее предпочтительным способом экранирования SQL параметров для PostgreSQL, в то время как addslashes() не должна использоваться с PostgreSQL.

Comment: @perfect это в случае, когда экранирование **вообще нужно**. PDO должен выполнять его самостоятельно, там **никакие** функции не должны быть нужны, ни `addslashes`, ни базоспецифичные.